# Display popup message on submit button

Tags: 7, javascript

For my contact form using form api and for my Drupal 7 built in user registration form, I need to display messages in a popup window.

> E.g: when user clicks on submit button on a contact form the `Thank you message` should display in a popup.

I have installed [Popup Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_message) module but unable to figure out how can I configure to set messages for my different forms.

Comment: @NishantP nope, what you linked is Webform, what he asks is Form API

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about code OP wrote, but does not show this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Better Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_messages) module

> Better Messages is a very simple module that provides "Popup-like" Drupal messages.

Or

[Purr Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/purr_messages)

> Do you want a more interestingly themed system message from Drupal? Enjoy Growl messages on OS X? Then this module is for you.

Or

[Nice messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/nicemessages)

> The Nice messages popup module changes how Drupals status, warning and error messages are showing up by giving flexible stylable nice looking fading little jQuery-popups like on Social networks at hand, provided by the small and fast jQuery jGrowl plugin. It can be activated globally or partially for certain pages / users and prevents the typical cluttering caused by error messages getting in the way by moving the grid and layout of a website up and down.

Comment: Thanku @Andrew solved my problem using Better message module

Comment: The OP is asking the following: "I have installed Popup Message module but unable to figure out how can I configure to set messages for my different forms." They just want to know how to enable pop-up messages using that module, not which other modules are available.

Comment: I have just installed `Better Message` module and it will display all messages in popup

Comment: I (also) like Andrew's answer. But in no way it answers the question as it currently looks like. Since the current question is something like "How to configure the Popup Message module?" ... and not something like "does anybody have suggestions for alternative modules to solve my configuration issue with the module I'm using now?". Therefor consider EDITING the question accordingly ... it may help to (a) remove the hold status and (b) reduce the downvotes of the question and (c) get additional answers ...

Comment: thanks for your help .Nice messages module help me to make the submit button message show as popup message .
Thanks again